# Approve Anchor Text - DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I am looking to use Conga to auto-generate a DocuSign document within Salesforce. Ideally, it would include steps for both approvers and signers, in the following order:

Routing order 1: recipient is Signer

Routing order 2: recipient is Approver

Routing order 3: recipient is Signer

Routing order 4: recipient is Approver

I imagine this requires that I embed an anchor tag for approval (much like I would embed \s1\ for signer). I, however, cannot find the tag for this. Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not believe the DocuSign for Salesforce integration currently has the anchor tagging (autoplace) feature configured for `Approve` tabs.

According to the [DocuSign for Saleforce Admin Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_for_Salesforce_Administrator_Guide.pdf) these are the currently available anchor types:

[image]